# Box2d медленный мир

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, typescript, box2d, pixijs

В общем вставляю такую штуку в игровой цикл:

```
this.app.ticker.add((delta: number) => {
            meter.tick();               
            this.world.Step(this.timeStep, this.velocityIterations, this.positionIterations, this.particleIterations);

            that.update(delta);
        });
```

тела падают медленно и движутся медленно

если делаю так все становится более менее норм

```
this.app.ticker.add((delta: number) => {
            meter.tick();
             for (let i: number = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                this.world.Step(this.timeStep, this.velocityIterations, this.positionIterations, this.particleIterations);
             }

            that.update(delta);
        });
```

Правильно ли я делаю?
Пробовал менять параметры тел они особо не влияют.

Проект тут https://github.com/likemyjob/PixiProjectArcanoid

В общем сделал так

```
 setInterval(() => {
            this.world.Step(this.timeStep, this.velocityIterations, this.positionIterations);
        }, 5);
```

работает более менее норм

Comment: Так может, у вас просто слишком низкая гравитация и действующие силы, а не медленная сцена?

Comment: @D-side 0,10  гравитация, 1/60 timeStep Если увеличить гравитацию, то тела просто меньше подпрыгивают но падают с той же скоростью

Comment: Значит слабо увеличиваете гравитацию, и/или материалам отдельных тел нужно поставить упругость (restitution) повыше, и/или ваша скорость воткнулась в лимит симуляции Box2D и вам надо пересмотреть масштабы, т. к. лимиты выбраны так, чтобы погрешности плавающей точки влияли минимально.

Comment: Знать бы как менять масштабы

Comment: Нашел как менять масштаб =) просто уменьшить размеры всех объектов

Comment: И помогло? Т. е. дело реально было в лимите симуляции?

Comment: @D-side нагуглил нашел один коммент, там было написано что рекомендуется размеры объектов делать от 0.1 до 10  сделал так и теперь нормально Думаю только delta time умножать на timeStep или нет. Теперь при гравитации 0,1 тела норм движутся при увеличении начинают намного быстрее

Comment: Собственно, это и имелось в виду под "пересмотреть масштабы". Масштабы между пикселями и физическими единицами. Мне стоило сразу развернуть мысль. Можете написать ответ!